# How can I use the alpha channel un Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, alpha

I mean, in Python. The transparency. I simply want to an image appear and slowly vanish, aka, get transparent.

My actual code.

```
def post_texto_1():
inicio = True
alpha = 255

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

while inicio:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    imagen_postTexto1.set_alpha(alpha)
    screen.blit(imagen_postTexto1, (0, 0))
    alpha -= 1
    if alpha == 0:
        inicio = False
    tex2 = u"¿Dónde estoy? ¿A dónde voy?"
    mostrar_mensaje(tex2, (255, 255, 255))
    print("El alpha de la imagen es : "+str(alpha))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I did used .convert_alpha() in my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`convert_alpha()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha), you change the pixel format of an image **including per pixel alphas**.

According to the PyGame documentation for [`set_alpha()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha), the alpha value will be **ignored**, if the Surface format (i.e. the image) contains **per pixel alphas**.

If you still need to display a transparent image and want to use `set_alpha()`, you could use PyGames [`set_colorkey()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey) method to set **one** color transparent.

Use the following function to vanish an image:

```
def vanish_image(image, screen, background_color):  
    image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
    image.set_colorkey((0,0,0)) #RGB-value for transparent color if needed

    alpha = 255

    while True:        
        if alpha < 0: #exit function if alpha is smaller than 0
            return

        alpha -= 1

        screen.fill(background_color) #"clear" last blitted image
        image.set_alpha(alpha)

        pygame.display.update(screen.blit(image,(0,0))) #blit new image onto surface and update only this area

        pygame.time.delay(20) #wait 20 milliseconds
```